# extract multiple matches from varchar or text column as rows from MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a string (varchar ) column in my DB and I would like to use SQL to so some simple group matching and extract the matches into rows.  Is there a way to accomplish this in plain SQL in mariaDB without a stored procedure or custom function?

Example:

```
 my_string ="this is a test string with x12345 and y1264 ...";
```

I am looking for something like this to extract all numbers starting with x or y into rows.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR("[xy][0-9]+") from my_string;
```

Expected result:

```
x12345
y1264
```

The reason I need the rows is that this will be part of a bigger query where I join these rows on a key in another table.

My above query only returns 1 row, the 1st result
x12345

Is there a way to obtain all matches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [JSON_TABLE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_table/) to extract all words in your string, then check if these words start with x or y and are followed by numbers.

You can simply convert your string to a JSON format by enclosing it with square brackets, enclosing each word with double quotations, and replacing every single space with a comma. So you can use this code to do that `CONCAT('["', REPLACE(myTxt, ' ', '","'), '"]')`.

Then you can use the JSON_TABLE as the following:

```
create table tbl(id int, myTxt TEXT);
insert into tbl values
  (1, 'this is a test string with x12345 and y1264'), 
  (2, 'this is a test xtest ytest string with x11111 and y11111 and x22222 and y22222');


SELECT id,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY W.rowid) num_order, 
       W.xy_val
FROM tbl
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE
  (
    CONCAT('["', REPLACE(myTxt, ' ', '","'), '"]'), 
    '$[*]' 
    COLUMNS 
      (
       rowid FOR ORDINALITY, 
       xy_val VARCHAR(32) PATH '$'
      )
  ) W
WHERE  W.xy_val REGEXP '[xy][0-9]'
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/_CH-vyR3)